# Missing bridge cast causes error in preprocessed source but not in real source

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

To compile a source file, clang preprocesses it at first and then compiles it. So if I run **clang -E**, I should get a preprocessed file, that can be compiled with **clang -c**. But the following code doesn't compile after preprocessing it.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    NSString* foo = @"bar";

    CFStringRef urlString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
        NULL,
        (CFStringRef)foo,
        NULL,
        (CFStringRef)@"",
        kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );

    CFRelease(urlString);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with **clang -c** ignoring that foo is cast to CFStringRef without __bridge. When the code is preprocessed, it doesn't compile anymore and clang complains about missing __bridge cast. Is there a flag to disable this behavior or a method to work around this?

Full clang command (used it for compiling and preprocessing with -E)

> clang -x objective-c -arch armv7s -fmessage-length=0
>   -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -c main.m

Comment: How about just adding the `__bridge` to the casts?

Comment: Show us the rest of the flags you’re passing to clang. My guess is that in one case you’ve enabled ARC and in the other case you haven’t.

Comment: Adding __bridge is not an option for me, because I am doing some transformations to the preprocessed source

Comment: @ElvissStrazdiņš: `clang -E main.m > main.i ; clang -x objective-c -c main.i` does not give any warnings with my Xcode 5.2.

Comment: @MartinR: you should enable ARC to see the error, add `-fobjc-arc` argument.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko: O yes, of course. Stupid error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare [ARC - implicit bridging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624983/arc-implicit-bridging):
"CFString.h" and other Core Foundation headers contain the macros

```
CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED
...
CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED
```

which are expanded to

```
_Pragma("clang arc_cf_code_audited begin")
...
_Pragma("clang arc_cf_code_audited end")
```

and that causes Clang to not complain about missing `__bridge` casts.

The pragmas are "consumed" by the preprocessor and therefore not in the preprocessed
file.
Since you are transforming the preprocessed source anyway, you can add
these pragmas to the start/end of the preprocessed file again.
Then there will be no warnings when compiling it.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot! I also tested other pragmas, they are all left after preprocessing, why is this consumed? Do you know, is it possible to disable this behavior?

Comment: @ElvissStrazdiņš: I have no idea.